# Nonstandard ordering on $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ordered-fields

> Show that the field of all numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt 2$ for $a,b\in\Bbb Q$ admits a nonstandard ordering (i.e. not the one coming from the standard ordering of real numbers).

Could anyone kindly help? I have been thinking a long time and have no clue about this.

Comment: Lexicographic order ? $a+b\sqrt2\le a'+b'\sqrt2\iff a<a'\text{ or }a=a'\text{ and } b\le b'$... Would have to verify if this is a field order, i.e. if it's compatible with addition and multiplication (else it would be quite useless for arithmetic problems...).

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS I don't think it works: For $a>1$, it holds $1<1+a\sqrt 2$, but $$(1+a\sqrt 2)^{-1}=\frac{1}{1-2a^2}-\frac{a}{1-2a^2}\sqrt 2<0$$ while the inverse of positive numbers should be positive. (or even, $(1+a\sqrt 2)^{-1}>1$ for $0<a<\varepsilon$ ).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli : I agree with you. I didn't say it was the good one, just a classical order that works here for ordering business, not for arithmetic business... It does not make $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$ an ordered field. In fact, the question lacks context...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the automorphism $a+b\sqrt{2} \mapsto a - b\sqrt{2}$ to "pull back" the ordering from the reals and get an ordering in which $\sqrt 2$ is negative. (I'm not really sure if this answers the question, though, as this ordering *does* come from a real embedding. But it does not come from the "standard" embedding which maps $\sqrt 2$ to $\sqrt 2$.)